Error setting up Node.js in Jenkins pipeline using NodeJS plugin
I'm learning Jenkins and working on setting up a basic pipeline to practice CI/CD with a simple React project. The pipeline is intended to:
Pull the latest commit from GitHub.
Use the Jenkins NodeJS plugin to install Node.js.
Build and publish the project on Docker Hub.
However, I’m encountering an issue with the Setup Node.js stage. The error seems to indicate that the nodejs step must be called with a body, but I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it.
code:
node {
    stage('Checkout') {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/main']],
            userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'my_repo_credentials']],
            extensions: [[$class: 'UserIdentity', name: 'DSL User', email: 'jenkins-dsl@newtech.academy']]
        ])
    }

    properties([
        pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'SCMTrigger', scmpoll_spec: 'H/5 * * * *']])
    ])

    stage('Setup Node.js') {
        echo "Starting Node.js Setup"
        nodejs('nodejs') 
        echo "Node.js Setup Complete"
    }

    stage('Docker Build and Publish') {
        script {
            docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'dockerhub') {
                def image = docker.build("my_docker_container_repo:latest")
                image.push("latest") 
            }
        }
    }
}

**Error output: **
Starting Node.js Setup
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.IllegalStateException: nodejs step must be called with a body
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:250)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeDescribable(DSL.java:503)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:199)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor186.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:180)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:163)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.methodCall(LoggingInvoker.java:117)
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: f05358ff-164e-4ca8-bf88-80d3cf00a106
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to prepare nodejs step
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeDescribable(DSL.java:505)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:199)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor186.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:180)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:163)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:178)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:182)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
    at PluginClassLoader for script-security//org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:152)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.methodCall(LoggingInvoker.java:117)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:18)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor185.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:147)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:17)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:49)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:180)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:422)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$wrap$4(CpsVmExecutorService.java:140)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:53)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$categoryThreadFactory$0(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 


In the Node.js setup step, instructions to configure Node.js are missing.
Your original code:
stage('Setup Node.js') {
    echo "Starting Node.js Setup"
    nodejs('nodejs') 
    echo "Node.js Setup Complete"
}

To resolve this, you could add a block within the nodejs step, like so:
stage('Setup Node.js') {
    echo "Starting Node.js Setup"
    nodejs('nodejs') {
        // Commands to execute in the Node.js environment
        sh 'npm install'
    }
    echo "Node.js Setup Complete"
}

